# how to refer to correct version of ruby on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I have previous version of ruby installed on my machine:

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I have installed another one:

```
Installed ruby-2.6.3 to /home/demouser5/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3
```

but when I execute ruby --version it says

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I want my system to refer to the version I have installed now i.e. 2.6.3 under /home/userdemo5. How do I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: but rvm is not installed on my ubuntu server. kindly let me know how to install it. I am using WSL for windows 10.

Comment: i installed rvm by following the installation steps mentioned on its website. but when i execute rvm use 2.6.3, it says command not found.